# tar: FOLDER: file changed as we read it however FOLDER is added to exclude

Tags: tar

tar command fails with error "*tar: artifacts: file changed as we read it*" although I added folder "artifacts" to exclude list

Following command works fine on one machine (ubuntu 16.04 with tar 1.28) but fails every time on other machine (ubuntu 18.04 with tar 1.29)

`tar -zcf artifacts/source_code.tar.gz * --exclude=artifacts`

I would like to tar all files and folder in the current dir excluding the directory where I am placing the tarball.
Please note that this commands is running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I execute that command, I get the following messages:

```
$ tar -zcf artifacts/source_code.tar.gz . --exclude=artifacts
tar: The following options were used after any non-optional arguments in archive create or update mode.  These options are positional and affect only arguments that follow them.  Please, rearrange them properly.
tar: --exclude ‘artifacts’ has no effect
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

So you have to put the `--exclude` first:

```
tar -zcf artifacts/source_code.tar.gz --exclude=artifacts *
```

Comment: Thank you @RalfFriedl! this actually fixed my issue. However, I need to mention that my original command works just fine on ubuntu 16.04 but not on ubuntu 18.04. Also on ubuntu 18.04, I haven't seen the error message you have!

Comment: They probably use different versions, I have GNU tar 1.31.